# ANDROID: Can I do SELECT with WHERE clause as String?

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have data in my database & the value of category is set to "**Breakfast**"

When I execute the below Query with **whereClause** as

1:**final String whereClause = RECIPE_ID + "=1";**

It returns me the data for that **RECIPE_ID**

But when I execute the query with **whereClause** as

2:**final String whereClause = RECIPE_CATEGORY + "='" + category.trim() + "'";**

It doesn't return anything...  So I guess my code is working fine as it returns result
RECIPE_ID   but I donno why it doesn't return data for the 2nd **whereClause**

Hope this makes sense..

```
final String whereClause = RECIPE_CATEGORY + "='" + category.trim() + "'";
        // ask the database object to create the cursor.
        cursor = db.query(
                RECIPE_TABLE,
                new String[]{
                            RECIPE_ID, 
                            RECIPE_CATEGORY,
                            RECIPE_THIS_TITLE,
                            RECIPE_THIS_SUBTITLE,
                            RECIPE_THIS_DESCRIPTION,
                            RECIPE_THIS_IMAGE,          
                            RECIPE_THIS_CALORIES,
                            RECIPE_THIS_FAT,
                            RECIPE_THIS_SATURATED,
                            RECIPE_THIS_TRANS,
                            RECIPE_THIS_CARBS,
                            RECIPE_THIS_SODIUM,
                            RECIPE_THIS_SUGARS,
                            RECIPE_THIS_SERVINGS,
                            RECIPE_THIS_COSTPERSERVING,
                            RECIPE_THIS_INSTRUCTIONS,
                            RECIPE_THAT_TITLE,
                            RECIPE_THAT_CALORIES,
                            RECIPE_THAT_FAT,
                            RECIPE_THAT_SATURATED,
                            RECIPE_THAT_TRANS,
                            RECIPE_THAT_CARBS,
                            RECIPE_THAT_SODIUM,
                            RECIPE_THAT_SUGARS,
                            RECIPE_THAT_PRICE
                        },
                        whereClause, null, null, null, null
        );
```

The above code will not return any results.  Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: You are not giving enough information.  Do you have data in your database?  Does 'category' have a value?  Are you using your cursor properly?  We cannot tell because there is not enough context.

Comment: Hoping `category` doesn't have value of `' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE Customers; --`.

Comment: I have edited my question so that it makes sense now, could you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to form a question here. Posting code does you no good. If your question is as you title implies, then yes you can do a search clause as a string. Just leave out the where. eg `dataId = 5` where 'where' is implied.

Edit: to address the question at the bottom that I missed, multiple things could be wrong. One may be that you dont have any data in the database. Or the where clause is executed and none of your data fits the criteria. Check your database. We can't help with that.

Comment: I have edited my question so that it makes sense now, could you please check

Comment: Well it still seems that your database may not have the data you think it does. The cursor cannot return a value if there is no value to return.

Comment: Yes, the data was there... After using SQLLite Database Browser I found that it was in other column, My bad... :(  Thank For the help